# VSCode Libraries not showing for New Java Project

Tags: java, database, oracle, visual-studio-code, jdbc

I was hoping someone could help me resolve some issues I'm having when creating a Java project in VSCode. I want to use the project to connect to a DB on Oracle and use JDBC to do so, but I can't seem to get my code to recognize `import oracle.jdbc.driver.*`I downloaded and have added ojdbc11.jar and ucp11.jar to the lib folder, but when I run the code I still don't get the output I want. I saw some online help that referred to a "Referenced Libraries" folder, but that isn't in my project (lib wasn't either, but I added the library manually.) I'm somewhat new to Java on VSCode (used Eclipse for the most part before, but I want to try and learn it on VSCode).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: What the Project looks like]

I *think* this is because the code isn't reading the jar files, but I don't see how to make it do so. When I add lines to the settings.json file it still doesn't seem to recognize them. I added `"java.project/referencedLibraries": [ "lib/**/*.jar"]` I tried completely reinstalling all my extensions but it didn't seem to fix the problem. Likewise refreshed VSCode to the latest release, but still no dice.

Comment: By the way: [*Introducing the Oracle Java Platform Extension for Visual Studio Code*](https://inside.java/2023/10/18/announcing-vscode-extension/).

Comment: You should learn to build your project using either Maven or Gradle. Either will locate and download the Oracle JDBC driver and install it into your app. The extension linked in my Comment above supports Maven & Gradle.